# How do I crop my background image?

Tags: css

I'm using a WrapBootStrap theme for my website, and want to crop the background image shown here:

www.getpowerhelp.com

Basically, I want to crop it from the bottom.

How do I do this using CSS? Relevant code is here:

**HTML FILE**

```
<div class="hero hero_agency">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

      <!-- Hero heading -->
      <h1 class="heading hero__heading">Get Your Money Back from NPower</h1>
```

**CSS FILE**

```
    .hero {
  position: relative;
  padding: 70px 0 100px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(108, 91, 123, 0.8) 0%, rgba(53, 92, 125, 0.8) 70%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(108, 91, 123, 0.8) 0%, rgba(53, 92, 125, 0.8) 70%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(108, 91, 123, 0.8) 0%, rgba(53, 92, 125, 0.8) 70%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cc6c5b7b', endColorstr='#cc355c7d', GradientType=0);
  content: "";
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .hero {
    padding: 220px 0 150px;
  }
}

.hero_agency {
  background-image: url(../img/bg_1.jpg);
  text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Put your code in a demo like jsfiddle or codepen so we can see the issue and help you easier

Comment: I see two images as backgrounds on the page. Could you clarify what do you want to achieve and with which of the images?

Comment: thanks @AlphaG33k , here's the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/xL3nqvmm/.

Comment: @user907860 i want to crop both of the background images by about 300px from the bottom.

Comment: it would be helpful if your fiddle had the images used for the background linked properly so they displayed in the result...

Comment: do you want the `.hero_agency` div to have a background image only at its bottom 300px ?

Comment: @FaisalKhalid I gave you a demo for two different ways, both have only the code you need no bloat. I did see your example after I finished setting you up with a codepen and I see alot of code that doesnt have to do with the issue at hand. I hope the two solutions I offered you  below help.

Comment: I would add another inner div with position absolute and fixed height for 300 px and attach the background to it

Comment: @user907860 i tried but this does not work..

Comment: do you want the gradient image to be cropped too?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `background-position: center center;` with `background-position: center bottom;` on your `.hero` class style, if thats what you mean by "crop it from the bottom"

For 300px from the bottom you can set it like this: `background-position: center -300px;`

Comment: thanks, it crops for sure but everything seems to "zoom in" as a result.  basically what i want is to keep the top part of the picture fixed, no change, just literally cut off 300 px from the bottom, thats it

Comment: if you want it fixed to the top then you could try `background-position: center top;`. It will appear zoomed in because of `background-size:cover;` will stretch the image to cover the dimensions of `.hero`

Comment: hm, ok. so how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of cropping and image come to mind for me:

One using an image to inside of a fixed height container set to `overflow: hidden` while another way would be to set the image as a background and use the `background-size` property along with the background-position property in order to achieve the same effect.

**Image way inside container**

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/QbQXLN

**CSS way single element**

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/eNVwOE

Comment: thanks, but i'm not sure how to apply this to my problem... what part of my  code do i change?